# How to create user and loging mongodb database on docker via docker-compose?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have a running mongodb on docker. I created user on it but I couldn't login with user credentials from docker-compose.

Here is my configurations:

Create user:

```
use database
db.createUser({user: "username", pwd: "password", roles: [{role: "readWrite", db: "database"}]});
```

docker-compose.yml

```
mongo:
  container_name: container
  image: mongo:latest
  env_file: .env
  entrypoint:
    MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGODB_AUTH_USER}
    MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGODB_AUTH_PASS}
```

But I am getting below error when trying to run `docker-compose up` command:

```
ERROR: for 177f1a769910_smartcap-mongodb  Cannot start service mongo: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME:username\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

How can I solve this problem? Could you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Change `entrypoint` to `environment`, like so:

```
mongo:
  container_name: container
  image: mongo:latest
  environment:
    MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGODB_AUTH_USER}
    MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGODB_AUTH_PASS}
```